# Snowflake + Power BI Direct Query with List Parameters Error - We cannot apply operator & to types Text and List

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerquery

Power BI direct query Error

I have a list **YEAR** of type Number.        Values ( 2020,2021,2022 )
I am using the list as a parameter in PowerBI Direct query but
Getting an error -  We cannot apply operator & to types Text and List.

Question : How to use the number list in direct query ?

***Query below***

= Value.NativeQuery(Snowflake.Databases("abcd.east-us-2.ADIC.snowflakecomputing.com","DATABRICKS"){[Name="SUPER"]}
[Data],
"select * from SUPER.SCHEMA1.INT_HIST WHERE YEAR IN (" & (YEAR ) & ")"  , null, [EnableFolding=true])

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

> Value.NativeQuery(Snowflake.Databases("abcd.east-us-2.ADIC.snowflakecomputing.com","DATABRICKS"){[Name="SUPER"]} [Data], "select * from SUPER.SCHEMA1.INT_HIST WHERE YEAR IN (" & **Text.Combine(List.Transform(YEAR,Text.From), ",")** & ")" , null, [EnableFolding=true])

Comment: I made changes to slicer and parameter to pass only one value from the slicer to Direct Query . Name of Parameter = FMONTHYEAR .                                                                               
  Direct query changed to - let
    Source = Value.NativeQuery(Snowflake.Databases("supernova.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com","GALAXY"){[Name="PLUTO"]}
    [Data]," SELECT * FROM SATURN.TABLE where MONTHYEAR = '"&Text.From(FMONTHYEAR)&"' " . But final table is not displayed and there is no error in syntax. Not sure what I am doing wrong here